# sinon expects validate only subset of properties

Tags: sinon

How can I validate only a subset of an objects properties using `sinon`s `.expects('').withArgs()` function and totally ignore all other properties **without exluding them one by one** using `sinon.match.any`?

E.g. `myObject` has about 20 properties and I just want to expect `myObject.name` equals `Alex`.

```
myClass.expects('update')
.withArgs({
  name: sinon.match('Alex')
  // what else to use here?
}) 
.yields(null, 'RESULT')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sinon.match(object)`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.2.0/matchers/#sinonmatchobject) which requires the value "to be not `null` or `undefined` and have at least the same properties" as the expectation:

```js
myClass.expects('update')
.withArgs(sinon.match({
  name: 'Alex'
}))
.yields(null, 'RESULT')
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try the quotes wheres your property was null ?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: myClass.expects('update')
.withArgs({
  name: sinon.match('Alex')
  property : "null"
}) 
.yields(null, 'RESULT')

Comment: I've updated my question for better explanation what I want to achieve